# How to upload only non-duplicate files with ngx-uploader

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-uploader

How to upload only non-duplicate files with ngx-uploader?
I don't see any option to distinct file names on upload? Can this be handled by some code, but not breaking the UI?
The files are added to queue and then handled by their status. I also want to upload it straight forward (see          // uncomment this if you want to auto upload files when added ).

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { UploadOutput, UploadInput, UploadFile, humanizeBytes, UploaderOptions } from 'ngx-uploader';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'app-home.component.html'
})
export class AppHomeComponent {
  options: UploaderOptions;
  formData: FormData;
  files: UploadFile[];
  uploadInput: EventEmitter<UploadInput>;
  humanizeBytes: Function;
  dragOver: boolean;
 
  constructor() {
    this.options = { concurrency: 1, maxUploads: 3, maxFileSize: 1000000 };
    this.files = []; // local uploading files array
    this.uploadInput = new EventEmitter<UploadInput>(); // input events, we use this to emit data to ngx-uploader
    this.humanizeBytes = humanizeBytes;
  }
 
  onUploadOutput(output: UploadOutput): void {
    switch (output.type) {
      case 'allAddedToQueue':
         // uncomment this if you want to auto upload files when added
         const event: UploadInput = {
           type: 'uploadAll',
           url: '/upload',
           method: 'POST',
           data: { foo: 'bar' }
         };
         this.uploadInput.emit(event);
        break;
      case 'addedToQueue':
        if (typeof output.file !== 'undefined') {
          this.files.push(output.file);
        }
        break;
      case 'uploading':
        if (typeof output.file !== 'undefined') {
          // update current data in files array for uploading file
          const index = this.files.findIndex(file => typeof output.file !== 'undefined' && file.id === output.file.id);
          this.files[index] = output.file;
        }
        break;
      case 'removed':
        // remove file from array when removed
        this.files = this.files.filter((file: UploadFile) => file !== output.file);
        break;
      case 'dragOver':
        this.dragOver = true;
        break;
      case 'dragOut':
      case 'drop':
        this.dragOver = false;
        break;
      case 'done':
        // The file is downloaded
        break;
    }
  }
 
  startUpload(): void {
    const event: UploadInput = {
      type: 'uploadAll',
      url: 'http://ngx-uploader.com/upload',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { foo: 'bar' }
    };
 
    this.uploadInput.emit(event);
  }
```

BUMP.